# How to allow to add super class as a reference in CMDBuild?

Tags: cmdb

I’m trying to create a reference attribute in a class. The reference is a super class "Asset". Firstly I created the domain

But the domain doesn’t show in the list of reference.

Could some give some ideas?

Thanks